# Сборка бинарников под Android через NDK

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, сборка

Рассмотрим на примере сборки простого бинарного файла  всеми любимого tar.

Итак, скачал значит NDK 18b2 отсюда https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/

Распаковал в `/home/user/ndk18b`

Скачал tar http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-latest.tar.gz

Вопросы вступительные:

1. куда извлекать исходники tar? В папку с ndk?
2. там уже есть свои файлы configure они нужны или нет?
3. в статьях создаются .mk файлы мне тоже надо создавать? Если да, то как? (файлов там вагон)
4. Есть ли какая то прогграмма для генерирования этих .mk Файлов?

tar обычно в терминале собираю так

```
./configure CC=gcc LDFLAGS=-static
```

Естественно все бинарники надо собирать статически.

Answer (score 2):

1) Кидаете исходники в свой каталог

2) Без понятия

3) Надо создавать - рученьками, `vi` вам в помощь :) - ладно шучу, любой текстовый редактор подойдет

4) По сути вам нужно всего 2 mk файла `Android.mk` - список того чего вы компилируете + флаги компилятора и второй `Application,mk` - не будет ничего смертельного если его контент будет такой:

```
APP_OPTIM := debug //создается версия для отладки
APP_ABI := all     //создаются либы для всех архитектур
```

5) Далее запускаете `build.sh` который лежит в корне NDK и молитесь :)

P.S. NDK умеет собирать либы для множества архитектур: ARM, MIPS, x86 и т.д.

Comment: Можно ли переделать makefile в Android.mk после конфигурации? Есть ли нормальный мануал по редактированию? В какой свой каталог? Любой? Я не пишу приложение на Java под ведро и sdk не установлена. Мне надо просто собрать бинарник из исходников под ведро.